# How to loop over carousel items using Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm fetching data from The Movie Database and i want the data retrieved to be displayed in my page on a carousel card with 3 slides.
Here is what i have done so far,
html,

```
 <div class="details"><!--Movie details are to be displayed here--></div>
```

Js,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function arrangement(resultFromServer) {
  let gridHtml=" ";
let poster= "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
let element= document.querySelector(".details");
let index= [].indexOf.call(element.parentElement.children, element);

let selected = resultFromServer.results[index];
for (let i = 0; i < resultFromServer.results.length; i++) {
const movieResults =resultFromServer.results[i];
gridHtml += `
<div id="multi-item-example" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">

<!--Indicators-->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!--/.Indicators-->

<!--Slides-->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<!--First slide-->
<div class="carousel-item active">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card mb-2">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="${poster}${movieResults.poster_path}"
        alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">${movieResults.title}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
          card's content.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`;

}
let myPage= document.querySelector(".details");
myPage.innerHTML=gridHtml;
}
</script>
```

What i get from this is that the movie details are returned in a vertical arrangement. Can someone help please !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use querySelector to check for an 'active' class.

```
 function myFunction(e) {
  var carousel = document.querySelector(".active");
  if(carousel !==null){
   carousel.classList.remove("active");
  }
 e.target.className = "active";
}
```

querySelector is used to find an active class on the page, if it exists (the if statement) then remove it and apply the active class on the next element,  iterating through the entire collection.